# Counter variable issue

Tags: c

I am trying to print the total no of occurrences of a digit in an array

I have initialized my counter variable and use the increment variable in the for loop. However, my program just prints the initialized variable.

```
int getkey(int arr[], int size, int key)
{
    int i, firstoccur, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
            break;
    }
    for(i=0; i <SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            counter++;
            firstoccur = i;
            return firstoccur;
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the counter to increase in order to count the no of occurences

Comment: I bet you'll get some unreachable warning for the last return, because you've already returned earlier. **Always read compiler warnings**. Besides, you declared the `size` parameter but never used it and used `SIZE` instead

Comment: Hi, re-think your code, especially if you really need two loops, to solve your problem. How would you do it by yourself on a piece of paper? (would you go through your numbers twice?)

Comment: `SIZE`?? You do know C is cASE-sENSATIVE, right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your second for loop:

```
firstoccur = i;
return firstoccur;
```

Also I don't think you need first for loop in your code.